# Getting error while ng serve. Using mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl, rxjs6, mapbox-gl-draw

**Have following versions:**

```
"angular": 6.0.3 
"rxjs": "^6.2.0",
"@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw": "^1.0.4",
```

> While **ng serve** Getting error: 
>   [image]

Could anyone help me out, will be appreciated..

Comment: What version of the Angular CLI are you using?

Comment: @p4r1 angular/cli: "6.0.3"

Comment: Adding ```node: { fs: 'empty'}```to webpack config file maybe helps.

Comment: @fatemefazli could you tell me where and in which file should place this code?

Comment: @KetanAkbari if you don't have ```webpack.config.js``` in your root dirctory, you can eject ```webpack.config.js``` from angular-cli by running
```$ ng eject``` and then add ```node: { fs: 'empty'}``` to your ```webpack.config.js``` file.

Comment: @fatemefazli i'm using angular cli-6.0.3, and in it `ng eject` is temp. disabled due to new `angular.json` format. could you suggest any other way.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have something to do with angular-cli.
Try adding this to the package.json

"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }

[Git issue for further details](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8272#issuecomment-464860910)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that Angular CLI v6 no longer ships with support for node built-in modules, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-369578814). This fix is outlined in a comment further down the issue thread [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-386154063):

In `polyfills.ts` add:

`(window as any).fs = window;`

Comment: Sorry, turns out that only works with `global`. There are [multiple](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8272) [issues](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5324) in the angular-cli repo for this problem, but the answer seems to be "working as indended".

Answer (score 0):

actually a way to resolve this issue was ignoring the `fs` require in `webpack.config.js` but in angular-cli version 6 and upper we can't eject `webpack.config.js` based on this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656) and [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10681#issuecomment-389153464).so we can't say webpack to ignore `fs`.it seems we can't use `fs` anymore in Angular-cli 6 and upper.You can declare the fs also by doing `declare var fs: any;`this solves `ng serve` but if you build the project then run `npm run serve`, will face the error:

> 'fs' is not defined.

Comment: in which file `declare var fs: any;` should be placed?

Comment: @KetanAkbari i'm not sure but you can try adding index.html:
```<script>  
var fs = require('fs');  
</script>```

Then in TS you can declare fs and access any method/property:
```declare var fs: any;```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and helps but these solutions not working

Comment: @KetanAkbari your welcome, we are trying to find the best solution and would be good mention me if you found any update on this question.